# casting from interface to QObject

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qobject

I have an interface class in a header file like this.

```
class Interface
{
...
}
#define InterfaceIID "Interface"
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(Interface, InterfaceIID)
```

which is expected to be implemented like this

```
class Implementation : public QWidget, public Interface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(Interface)
    ...
}
```

I have pointers to objects implementing my interface being passed around in my application. Now i know know that every Interface object is also a QWidget because that is the only supported use case.

My question is now, when i am in need of a QWidget object, how do i cast my Interface object to a QWidget?

```
qobject_cast<QWidget*>(interface) //does not compile
dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(interface) //works but is it the right way?
```

Is using dynamic_cast() the only way? I can cast from QWidget to Interface using qobject_cast() but the reverse does not work.

I understand that dynamic_cast() is unsafe across shared libraries and hence i'm trying to avoid it.

What is the right approach?

Comment: Cast the `Interface` to `Impelemntation` first and then cast `Implementation` to `QWidget`. I doubt `Interface` can be casted to a `QWidget` since they dont seem to be a part of the same inheritance chain.

Comment: @rozina  QWidget could potentially be a base implementation of Interface (no way of knowning from the code given), so a cast from Interface* to QWidget* could work.  dynamic_cast will give the answer safely.

Comment: @rozina Unfortunately, I cannot do that. Where this cast happens, the code does not know the implementation. It only knows the interface and assumes that the implementation would have also inherited from QWidget as documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one is right. `qObjectCast` is ment to cast a QObject to "anything", not the other way around. Thats what dynamic casts are for:

```
QObject *intfObject = pluginLoader.instance();
Interface *intf = qobject_cast<Interface *>(intfObject);//only works if the object has Q_INTERFACES(Interface)
QWidget *intfWidget = dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(intf);
```

Note: the `qobject_cast` above could easily be replaced with a `dynamic_cast`. However, if possible, always use `qobject_cast`. Reason (from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast)):

> The qobject_cast() function behaves similarly to the standard C++ dynamic_cast(), with the advantages that it doesn't require RTTI support and it works across dynamic library boundaries.

It uses Qts metasystem (QMetaObject) to perform the cast. And, in addition to that, it seems to be way faster then `dynamic_cast`.

The reason you can't use the qobject_cast to cast the interface to a `QWidget` is that the interface itself does not inherit QObject (and does not have the `Q_OBJECT` macro). Thus, it has no metaobject and `qobject_cast` cannot be used.

**EDIT:**
One way to avoid dynamic casting is to always keep the plugin as a `QObject`. If you need it as widget, cast it with `qobject_cast`. Same goes for your `Interface`. As long as you store/pass around the instance as `QObject`, you will never have to dynamic_cast.

Note: If you need to know the kind of plugin, create a small wrapper classes for each of the interfaces.

Comment: Is it then safe to use dynamic_cast()?. The interface and the code doing the casting is in one library (in my case, from the main application) and the implementation comes from another library (a plugin).

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Because Qt loads the plugins "the right way". At least for me the dynamic cast has always worked for now. But if you feel unpleasant with that solution, check my edited post.